# How to name processes and insert values in respective process as named in UNIX

Tags: c, linux

I need to create processes using fork and assign respective values to them according to their names/labels. And then transfer the values using pipes() in C language. My question is, is there a way to name processes?

Comment: That's great. It seems you forgot to ask a question though.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me, but what's your actual question? What have you tried? We aren't going to write it all for you, that's for sure.

Comment: My question is, is there a way to name the processes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Each process has an unique *identifier*, [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier). In Linux (as well as in all POSIXy and Unix systems) these identifiers are positive integers, with 1 being special, [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).

(By *unique*, above, I mean that every active (running) process and zombie process have their own PID, and no two share the same PID. However, old PIDs are eventually reused, sometimes within seconds; it depends on the system. Do not expect the PID of a dead process to stay unused!)

When you fork a child process, [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) returns `(pid_t)0` in the child process, and the child process PID in the parent process. By storing the PIDs of the child processes you create in an array, the parent process can tell which child is which.

Each process can always call [`getpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) to find out what it's own PID is.

A process can also call [`getppid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) to find out the PID of their parent process (the PID of the process that called `fork()` that created this process). However, if the real parent has already died/exited, `getppid()` will return 1. (This is also half of the reason we have an init process. The init process is responsible for exactly two things: being the parent of orphan processes, and reaping them when they die; and to start all the other processes when the operating system boots up.)

Neither `getpid()` or `getppid()` can ever fail; you can rely on them to always return the respective PIDs.

Overall, this kind of design is extremely common in practice. All daemons that use multiple processes to do their work, do basically exactly this. It means this exercise is relevant in practice, too.